# Ошибки в редакторе Php Designer

Tags: yii2

Использую PHP designer. Но например в простейше функции от yii

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['logout'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['logout'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
```

выдает ошибку на слове return syntax Error unexpected "[" хотя все работает нормально. Как быть?

Answer (score 0):

Где-то в настройках *PHP designer* видимо стоит пункт, что версия редактируемого PHP - 5.3. Потому что до версии 5.4 массивы объявлялись через `array()`. Нужно найти эту настройку и поставить версию ту, которой действительно пользуетесь.

в *PHPStorm*, например, делается вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]